# Add filter hook to show the dates for sales when the product is a variable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am trying to get Woocommerce to show the scheduled ending date for variable products. This code snippet below works on simple woocommerce products but not for prodcuts with variations. I tried with the global variable $variations, $product, #product_id. The variations have all the same sales date (from/to).

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_html', 100, 2 );
function custom_price_html( $price, $product ){
    global $post;
    $sales_price_to = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_sale_price_dates_to', true);
    if( $sales_price_to != "" )
    {
        $sales_price_date_to = date("d/m/y", $sales_price_to);

        return str_replace( '</ins>', ' </ins> <br /><br />(Sales end on: '.$sales_price_date_to.')', $price );
    }
    else
    {
        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );        
    }
}
```

Any ideas please response to my question.
Thanks for your help in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok have tried this, isnt working as good but I got to display an unknown date in the variable product hahahhaha, I need this but this might enlighten to make it work :D, is and advance, im not good at all in php :D

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_html', 100, 2 );
function custom_price_html( $price, $product )
{
    global $post;
    $sales_price_to = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_sale_price_dates_to', true);
    $sales_price_to_variable = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', true);

    if($product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $sales_price_to != "" )
    {
        $sales_price_date_to = date("j M y", $sales_price_to);
        return str_replace( '</ins>', ' </ins> <div style="margin-top:10px;">(Descuento hasta '.$sales_price_date_to.')</div>', $price );
    }

    else if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){
        $sales_price_date_to = date("j M y", $sales_price_to_variable);
        return str_replace( '</ins>', ' </ins> <div style="color:white;">(Descuento hasta '.$sales_price_date_to.')</div>', $price );
    }
    else
    {
        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
    }
}
```